# Formatting stream spaces

Tags: c++

I have been trying to use .pushback to format my string so that it prints just a space between every word.

So I was trying to use a .push_back, however that doesn't work with integers.

```
std::string FormatVehicleString(std::string year,
    std::string make,
    std::string model,
    double price,
    double mileage)
{

    year.push_back(5);
    make.push_back(5);
    model.push_back(5);
    price.push_back(5);
    mileage.push_back(5);

}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, is there another value type that will incorporate strings and integers?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `std::ostringstream`.

```
std::string FormatCarInfo(std::string year,
    std::string make,
    std::string model,
    double price,
    double mileage)
{
   std::ostingstream out;
   out << year << " ";
   out << make << " ";
   out << model << " ";
   out << price << " ";
   out << mileag ;

   return out.str();
}
```

Another option is to use `std::to_string`.

```
std::string FormatCarInfo(std::string year,
    std::string make,
    std::string model,
    double price,
    double mileage)
{
   return ( year + " " + make + " " + model + " " + 
            std::to_string(price) + " " + std::to_string(mileage) );
}
```